# integrating validation module in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am using the following node module for validation: https://github.com/chriso/node-validator

Now, suppose I want to check on an user input like this  `check('abc').isInt();` I noticed that it basically throws an error!

I am pretty new with node.js but it seems to me that having to use `try{}catch(e){}` blocks every time I need to check on a user input is a bit on an overkill.

wouldn't it make more sense to have something like

```
if (check('abc').isInt()) {
  // Do things here
  next(null, stuff_I_want_to_return)
} else next(error);
```

instead of

```
try{
  check('abc').isInt()
  next(null, stuff_I_want_to_return)
} catch(e) { next(e); }
```

?? I have no idea, please clarify on what is the best approach to have in this case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their docs say you can do this

```
var Validator = require('validator').Validator;
var v = new Validator();
v.error = function(msg) {
    console.log('Fail');
}
v.check('abc').isInt(); //'Fail'
```

That way you won't have to do try catch

Answer (score 0):

Check module [core-util-is](https://npmjs.org/package/core-util-is) providing functions introduced in Node v0.12.

In your case, method **isNumber** would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's still fairly common in Node.js for synchronous functions to `throw` as they don't usually have a callback to pass an `error` to. But, they still need some way to deliver it to calling code and `return error;` would generally be an unexpected choice.

Though, the documentation for `node-validator` does include an example for extending `Validator`s with a `getErrors()` method under "[Error Handling](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator#error-handling)."

> ```
> Validator.prototype.error = function (msg) {
>     this._errors.push(msg);
>     return this;
> }
>
> Validator.prototype.getErrors = function () {
>     return this._errors;
> }
> ```

Which could be used to report errors without `throw`:

```
var validator = new Validator();

if (validator.check('abc').isInt()) {
    next(null, ...);
} else {
    next(validator.getErrors());
}
```

Note: The `_errors` property should [already be defined](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator/blob/1.5.1/lib/validator.js#L45) after using `.check()`.